# Create a function genSet() that takes in a list of numbers and returns a sorted set in python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I am new to python and trying to solve this example on [pyschool](http://pyschool.com)
I need to write a function,

a) that takes a list of numbers

b) removes duplicates from the list

c) returns a sorted set:

In python, example :

```
>>> genSet([5,4,8,4,9,8])
[4, 5, 8, 9 ]
>>> genSet([3,-2,-1,-1,3,-2,0])
[-2, -1, 0, 3 ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing Duplicates:

```
>>> t = [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> t
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list(set(t))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> s = [1, 2, 3]
>>> list(set(t) - set(s))
[8, 5, 6, 7]
```

Sort the List:

```
>>> sorted([5, 2, 3, 1, 4])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Now you could write your custom function, that removes duplicates and sort.

The following code snippet works:

```
def genSet(clist):
    t = list(set(clist))
    return sorted(t)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print genSet([5,4,8,4,9,8])
    print genSet([3,-2,-1,-1,3,-2,0])
```

If you want to iterate over multiple list try this:

```
a = [
        [5,4,8,4,9,8],
        [3,-2,-1,-1,3,-2,0]
    ]

for aa in a:
    print genSet(aa)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It worked.. however I wanted to try using a for loop : (

Comment: Please vote my answer if it works :). Please tell me more about using you for loop and i will try to help you

Comment: What i was thinking of is a) iterate the list using for loop b) compare the values using if  else and c) assign it to  new list.

Comment: for loop that iterate over multiple lists ?

Comment: If you want to iterate:     a = [
            [5,4,8,4,9,8],
            [3,-2,-1,-1,3,-2,0]
        ]

    for aa in a:
        print genSet(aa)

Comment: by using a sorting algorithm like bubble sort

Answer (score 0):

`set` will automatically remove duplicates and `sorted` will sort the list.

```
def genSet(l):
  return (sorted(set(l)))
```